# Which client side JS framework is best to work with Salesforce

Tags: javascript, angularjs, framework

I am a newbie and I want to use client side JS framework in my org (Salesforce Classic).

I am aware of following JS framework:

1. Vue
2. Angular
3. React

So I want to know which client side JS framework is best to work with Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that Salesforce's own client side JS framework the [Lightning Component Framework](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_framework.htm) should also be on your list. Those components can be presented in Classic via [Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/02/lightning-components-visualforce-lightning.html) and knowledge gained and potentially the components too can be leveraged if you make the move to Lightning Experience in the future.

You may find this blog post useful as you make your decision: [LockerService and Lightning Container Component: Securely Using Third-Party Libraries in Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html).